# Realtime TCP Receiver in Powershell

Tags: powershell, tcp

I've been trying to make a TCP client in Powershell that sends and receives data, but I don't know how to make my script display server output in real-time. I've tried to do this with Start-Job and Receive-Job, but to make the job show its output you have to call Receive-Job every time. My goal is to have PS terminal available for reading input by Read-Host and at the same time wait for data from the server and display it. My code is:

```
$server = "127.0.0.1"
$port = 2137

$connection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($server, $port)
$stream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream $connection.GetStream(),$false,({$true} -as [System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback])
$stream.AuthenticateAsClient("Foo")

$reader = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader($stream)
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)

$writer.WriteLine("aadmin")
$writer.Flush()

$writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)

$read = $reader.ReadInt32()
if($read -eq 0)
{
    $writer.Write(0)
    Write-Host "Password: " -NoNewline
    $password = Read-Host
    $writer.Write($password)
    
    $read = $reader.ReadInt32()
    if($read -eq 0)
    {
        $receiver = Start-Job {
            while($true)
            {
                if($connection.Available -ge 1)
                {
                    $read = $reader.ReadString()
                    Write-Host $read
                }
            }
        }

        do
        {
            Write-Host "[admin@server] > " -NoNewline
            $in = Read-Host
            $writer.Write($in)

            Receive-Job $receiver

        } while($in -ne "exit" -and $connection.Connected)
    }
    else { Write-Host "Error: ?" }

    Stop-Job $receiver
    Remove-Job $receiver -Force

    $reader.Close()
    $writer.Close()
    $stream.Close()
    $connection.Close()
}
else { Write-Host "Error" }
```